# background color not showing for a div but other styles do

Tags: css

Other style works on the content div but not background color.

I see the color when I press <kbd>f12</kbd> but for some reason it is not applied to the view.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
        
.content {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 40px auto 140px;
    background-color: rgb(72, 59, 59);
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="title-section">
        <p>Lägg ut annons!</p>
    </div>
    <form action=" {{ route('create-ad') }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for=""></label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for=""></label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for=""></label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for=""></label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Lägg ut annons!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

*Please help me out here.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `background-color: rgb(72, 59, 59); !important`

If that doesn't work try to add background-color to other elements to debug the problem

The global styling `*` or bootstrap might be the reason why you're having that issue

Comment: Don't you mean background-color: rgb(72, 59, 59) !important; But that didn't work either

Comment: I don't have bootstrap but tailwind is installet because it is a laravel project, but I want my own styling

Comment: If you have chrome dev tools or any dev tools, try to hover over the content div element and see what's happening with the background-color

Comment: I changed * to body and it works fine now, thanks man!

Comment: But why is that? I will rate your answer the best, but it tells me to wait five minutes

Comment: I honestly never tried to add a background-color to all the elements, you should put the background-color separately to each element to avoid this kind of problems

Comment: Sometimes you can enforce the backgroundColor using JavaScript on some elements

Comment: Other methods include using the `!important` flag

Comment: I personally use dev-tools to debug the css problems and use css selectors to avoid using `!important`

Comment: That is some good advice. A big problem in the webdev community and tutorials that they just show you things without any further explanation, or sometimes show the quickest way but not the proper or secure. I didn´t know it was a bad idea to code admin status in the user table till a friend pointed it out and told me it should be two separate tables.

Comment: you shouldn't use `important`

Comment: Yes, the usage of `!important` should be done only when it's necessary